# SSIS:Unable to remove Column headers in Flat file destination

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, ssis-2012

I am using DataFlow task inside ForLoop Container. What am i excatly doing is that DFT will append a batch of 100 rows each time the for loop will run. But every time, it append rows, Headers are also appended.

I have tried by changing Flat File Connection Manager Editor(General) properties.Setting Header rows to skip to 2. But Still headers are appended. Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

First, add an SSIS integer variable in the scope of the Foreach Loop or higher - I'll call this RowCount - and make its default value negative (this is important!).  Next, add a Row Count to your Data Flow, and assign the result to the RowCount SSIS variable we just made.  Third, select your Connection Manager (don't double-click) and open the Properties window (F4).  Find the Expressions property, select it, and hit the ellipsis (...) button.  Select the ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow property, and use an expression like this:

[@User::RowCount] < 0

Now, when your package starts, RowCount has the static value of -1 or another negative number.  When the data flow starts for the first time in your loop, the ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow property will have a value of TRUE.  When the first data flow completes, the row count (even if it's zero) is written to the RowCount variable.  On the second interation of the loop, the Connection Manager is then reconfigured to NOT write column names...

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5a752fa5-1b3c-4d39-845c-b6cb7a2eb3fb/destination-flat-file-repeated-header-columns?forum=sqlintegrationservices